# How do I clean all the Flutter and Android Studio workspace?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Since I worked with Flutter on a Windows 10 machine, I faced a huge consumption of storage space.
It is over 1 month that I am working on a project and continuously building the project and I can see my space reducing day by day.
I tried Flutter clean, AVD cache clean, delete gradle folder under my local, I deleted also different caches in the android folder. I can only get some Gigabytes, but it's not enough. While working it uses more than I deleted.
If it can help, my flutter doctor is below.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1316], locale it-IT)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Even though it shows 2 issues on plugins, Flutter and Dart are both installed on Android studio and I was always able to work over VSCode without any problem.

[image]

To give you an example of a one day consumption: yesterday I had 7Gb free in the morning and it became 900Mb in the evening.

I used SpaceSniffer to better check what app is consuming space (with no results)
[image]

Is there any chance to definitely clean something somewhere to get some more Gigabytes?

**Short update!**

After a system reboot now my pc shows 7Gb of free space again!
OK but Android studio (or flutter sdk, don't know) is still consuming storage space. Consider it was over 20Gb one month ago when I started to work with this sdk.

Comment: You can try to run the app on the connected devices instead of Android emulators.

Comment: Yes, I did it without any issues. But I didn't understand you sentence! Why did you suggest it?

Comment: Android emulators need system-images which are huge. You can save that area by using a connected device.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! It definitely could be a solution!

Comment: Ok, then you can accept this as a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65774702/10659482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete your system-images to get some more Gigabytes.

```
  C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\
```

Answer (score 0):

> Windows + R  ->  temp  ->  delete all files
>
> Windows + R  ->  %temp% ->  delete all files

Comment: Thanks! I could only find 300 Mb, better than nothing yes, but I think there are still many more gigabytes missing.